# machine learning python train eror

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis

I am using train commands while doing bitcoin data analysis and I encountered an error :

```
data = df.set_index('Date')

dataset = df.values

training_data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset) * .8)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data_len, :]


x_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range (60, len(train_data),1):
    x_train.append(train_data[i:60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])



x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)

model =Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True , input_shape =(x_train.shape[1],1)))
```

**On the last line it should work fine but on the last line I get this error**

> slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node
> lstm_6/strided_slice_2}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT,
> begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0,
> shrink_axis_mask=1](lstm_6/transpose, lstm_6/strided_slice_2/stack,
> lstm_6/strided_slice_2/stack_1, lstm_6/strided_slice_2/stack_2)' with
> input shapes: [0,?,1], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors:
> input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Comment: If the dimension of train_data is (0,), you may have the error.